# Water traveling on a letter in a water feature

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, flow, surface-tension, adhesion

Difficult for me to ask as I'm not a physicist.

Assume you have a water feature in the form of a waterfall where the water runs down a wall. On this wall, there are letters attached by a raised platform. The water travels down the wall and when it hits the perpendicular platform, travels parallel to the ground and off the letter attached. This causes splashing around the water feature.

[image: water feature]

My question is why? I assume it has something to do with the force in which the water travels down the wall vs the ability of water to "stick" together?

I am wondering if there is a way to design an attachment that might minimize this effect, but I don't understand the phenomenon yet.

Answer (score 1):

As one can observe by pouring water on a flat surface, the speed it picks up by falling allows it to scoot sideways or even uphill to some extent. In addition, after a drop separates, the rebound tends to spread the surrounding liquid on the underside. And hydrophilicity of the solid surface encourages wetting.

To suppress the spreading, applying a hydrophobic coating might be useful, although such coatings can't really resist inundation.